# Publish a DocumentApp Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, add-on

I have a DocumentApp add-on that performs calculations similar to a program called MathCad or SMath.  I've pretty much finished it as a library.  Now I want to publish it so others can use it.  Can anyone give me advise and the steps I need for Google to make it available from their store?

I've been testing it with an add-on menu and a sidebar.  And there are several scripts that would need to be installed with the document to work with the menu and the library.

It also can save the Logger.log text to a file so that it can be viewed seperatedly and sent to me for debugging but I'm not sure if I can include Drive services with an add-on.

Any advise, tips and comments welcome.

The link provided below helped but I'm still stuck.

My proposed add-on has a sidebar that communicates with the server to place text in the document or perform other actions.  How do I get the server routine to execute from the library rather then the Document script.

```
function helpOnClick() {
  try {
    google.script.run.runCalcPadRequest({ name: "showHelp" });
  }
  catch(err) {
    showMessage("Error in JS_Sidebar.helpOnClick: "+err);
  }
};
```

Right now for testing I have in the Document script which calls runCalPadRequest in the library.

```
function runCalcPadRequest(request) {
  try {
    return CalcPad.runCalcPadRequest(request);
  }
  catch(err) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
};
```

Also how do I get the Add-on menu items to be added from the library.  This way the Document script is completely empty and everything is coming from the library.  The examples talk about Cards for Workgroup Add-ons but this is a Editor Add-on.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For how to publish an add-on, take a look at the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview). As it's currently written, I think your question is too broad, so I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Thanks you.  I think that is exactly what I was looking for